# Finding equation for volume of rectangular Prism?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have been stuck on this question for a while and would appreciate it if someone were to post a detailed step process of how they achieved an answer to part **a**

A closed rectangular box has length $x$ cm, width $y$ cm, and height $h$ cm. It is to be made from $300$ sq. cm of thin sheet metal, and the perimeter of the base is to be $40$ cm.

**a)** Show that the volume of the box is given by $V = 150h − 20h^2$.

**b)** Hence find the dimensions of the box that meets all the requirements and has the maximum possible volume.

I have come up with the following equations:

1. $40 = 2x + 2y$ (perimeter of base)
2. $300 = 2xh + 2xy + 2hy$ (equation for surface area)

I have attempted in making either $x$ or $y$ the subject in equation 1, and substituting it into equation 2, however always end up with
$150 = -x^2 + 20x + 20h$ when trying to find the expression for volume. I'm unsure where I went wrong.

Thanks for your time

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. I have updated the question to seem more appropriate. Thanks for your correction

Comment: Hint: from the equation, you have marked as 2. , divide by 2 to get $150 = hx+hy+xy$. Then, $150 = h(x+y) + xy$. Which gives you $150 - 20h = xy$ using the equation marked as 1. Now, use the fact that $xyh = V$ to complete the proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to detail the hint in the comments:
You have already got $$2x+2y = 40$$
and
$$2xh+ 2yh + 2xy = 300 $$
Divide both equations by $2$ to get:
$$x+y = 20 \tag{1}\label{1}$$$$xh+yh+xy = 150\tag{2}\label{2}$$
Volume of a cuboid (or a rectangular prism) with dimensions $x,y,h$ is given by:
$$V = xyh \iff xy = \frac Vh\tag{3}\label{3}$$
From $\eqref{2}$, $$150 = xh+yh+xy = h(x+y) + xy$$
Put the value of $x+y$ found in $\eqref{1}$ in this equation to get
$$150 = 20h+xy$$
Put the value of $xy$ found in $\eqref{3}$
$$150 = 20h + \frac Vh$$
Multiplying by $h$ and rearranging the terms completes the proof.

---

We can also use the equation you arrived at:
$$150 = 20h + 20x - x^2$$
$$150 = 20h + x(20 - x)$$
But, from $\eqref{1}$, $20 - x = y$ :
$$150 = 20h+xy$$
Further steps are the same as in the above method.